# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when selecting in CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question. I keep getting an error

```
CASE WHEN j.PHPPDT = '00010101' THEN '0' ELSE j.PHPPDT END AS NEWPPDT,

CASE WHEN j.PHPDTE = '00010101' THEN '0' ELSE j.PHPDTE END AS NEWPROMDT
```

Columns `j.PHPPDT` and `j.PHPDTE` are of datatype `DATE`.

When I run just them, the code seems to run. However, later with my code I create another CTE and need to select them and then  I get a mistake

```
 NEWPPDT AS PrintersPortDate,
 NEWPROMDT AS PromiseByDate,
```

The error is:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I am not really sure where and how to fix it, because normally when such things happen I just use

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(8), NEWPPDT ))
```

but here it doesn't help. Further, I am not sure I understand where to even insert it. Should I insert it to `j.PHPPDT` in my case statement or when I select the column...

It is pretty confusing. Does someone know what might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using some default date value instead of '0'

```
CASE WHEN j.PHPPDT = '00010101' THEN '12/31/2099' ELSE j.PHPPDT END AS NEWPPDT,
CASE WHEN j.PHPDTE = '00010101' THEN '12/31/2099' ELSE j.PHPDTE END AS NEWPROMDT
```